# Bad behavior in the Firefox Javascript debugger

Tags: javascript, firefox

I've created a very simple script:

```
<script>    
    var a = null;

    if (a == null) {
        console.log('a is null');
    }
    else {
        console.log('a is not null');
    }
</script>
```

When I open the debugger tab in the developer tools and I start debugging the script I realized that the script is executed as expected but the debugger after execute the statement *console.log('a is null');* when I press F10 to go to the next statement the debugger stop in the another *console.log* statement in the else *console.log('a is not null');* but the debugger doesn't execute it (as expected)

But this is not the expected behavior so when I'm debugging complicated code I don't know whether the debugger is executing the else statements or not.

I tried the same in Google Chrome and the debugger works as expected. After pressing F10 in the statement *console.log('a is null');* the debugger finished the script's execution.

Is this a bug or I'm missing something?

Also I've tested the same code in Firefox for XUbuntu 14.04 and the same is happening (I don't remember now what version of Firefox is but I think it's about 30.x) so this behavior is old enough.

I did the test now with Firefox 45 and I get the same behavior.

Here's a screenshot of the debugger after pressing F10 in the statement *console.log('a is null');*

[image]

Like I said before this statement is not executed. It can be verified in the *Console* tab.

The question is: Is this a bug or I'm missing something?

Comment: The same happen in Firefox Developer Edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1255631) in Firefox. This is purely a presentation problem. We try to show the end of the function, but for some strange reasons we actually show the last expression inside the last block.

Comment: Hi @evilpie, thank you for your quick response. I see that it has been reported as a bug. Can you please tell me if it will be fixed in the next release?